# Full or incremental scraping - What do people use?

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a question in regardes to scraping content off websites. Lets imagine in this example we are talking about content on classified style sites, like for example Amazon or Ebay.
Important notes about this content is that it can change and it can be removed.

The way I see it I have two options:

1. A full fresh scrape on a daily basis. I start the day with a blank
   database schema and fully rescrape each site every day and insert
   the content into the fresh database.
2. An incremental scrape, whereby I start with the content that was
   scraped yesterday, and when rescraping the site I do the following:

   ```
   Check existing URL      
           Content is still online and is it the same - Leave in DB                        
           Content is not availiable - Delete from DB      
           Content is different - Rescrape content
   ```

My question is, is the added complexity of doing an incremental scrape actually worth it, are there any benefits to this? I really like the simplicity of doing a fresh scrape each day but this is my first scraping project and I would really like to know what the scraping specialists do in scenarios like this.

Comment: A daily full scrape of Amazon or Ebay? Doesn't sound realistic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer depends on how you are using the data you have scraped. Sometimes the added complexity is worth it, sometimes it is not. **Ask yourself: what are the requirements for my scraper and what is the minimal amount of work that I need to do to fulfill these requirements?**

For instance, if you are scraping for research purposes and it is easier to for you to do a fresh scrape everyday, then that might be the road you want to take.

Doing an incremental scrape is definitely more complex to implement just as you said, because you need to make sure you have changed content is handled correctly (unchanged, changed, removed). Just make sure you also have a method for handling **new content** as well.

That being said, there are reasons why incremental scraping may be justified or even necessary. For instance if you are building something on top of your scraped data and cannot afford downtime due to active scraping work, you may want to consider incremental scraping.

Note also that there is not just a single way of implementing incremental scrapes: many kinds of incremental scrapes can be implemented. For instance, you may want to prioritize some content over other, say update popular content more often than unpopular. The thing here is that there is no upper limit in how much sophistication you can add to your scrapers. In fact, one could view search engine crawlers as highly sophisticated incremental scrapers.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a cloud based app that allows you to automate your scraping.

It turns websites into JSON/CSV
You can choose to download the updated full data-set on a daily basis or just the implemental differences.

[This example of a daily recurring scrape job for movie showtimes in Singapore](https://dev.krake.io/krakes/24)